# SAS: Stack files after checking that they exist

Tags: sas, partition, datastep

I am going through a bunch of files that are partitioned by calendar year and other variables. What I wanted to do is to partition them by fiscal year (based on a date variable that exists on the records). For example, to create FY2010 file, I would need to stack CY2009 and CY2010 files (let’s call these files file_2009 and file_2010) and subset to FY2010 records. However, either one or both of the files might not exist. What I wanted to do is, if one of the files does not exist then just use the other one. If both exit then use both. Otherwise, do nothing. The method I came up with was a bit less compact that I would like. Any ideas on the best way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: Please post the method you came up with so we have something to compare with; and preferably some example (Dummy) data that is sufficient to show what you mean.

Comment: Are your CY20xx files existing SAS datasets or are they external files?

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, the files are partitioned by calendar year, and other variables. And for some combination of CY and the these variables, the SAS datasets don't exist. I'm not sure if that answers your question.

Comment: Splitting a file up into several year-specific files is usually not a good idea. Even if you have to do that as a final step, maybe first step is just to stack all the datasets you have into one dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I will leave the splitting logic up to you - as others have commented, this is seldom a good idea in SAS as it's nearly always simpler to achieve the same result via by-group processing.

This is the simplest method I could think of for combining your files.

```
/*First, generate some dummy data*/

data cy2002 cy2004 cy2005;
      do year = 2002,2004, 2005;
            do _n_ = 1 to 10;
                  date =mdy(ceil(ranuni(1)*12),1,year);
                  format date yymmdd10.;
                  if year = 2002 then output cy2002;
                  if year = 2004 then output cy2004;
                  if year = 2005 then output cy2005;
            end;
      end;
run;

/*
  Generate a listing of all sas datasets in the appropriate library.
  For simplicity, assume these are sequentially named and are the only datasets in the library.
*/

ods listing close;
ods output members = members;
proc datasets lib = work memtype=data;
run;
quit;
ods listing;

/*Use the listing dataset to create a view that pieces together all of the calendar year datasets*/ 

data _null_;
      set members end = eof;
      if _n_ = 1 then call execute('data combined /view = combined; set ');
      call execute(name);
      if eof then call execute('; run;');
run;
```

You can then use the view to calculate the financial year based on the date and use it for whatever further processing is required.